# ProgressBar while taking Database bakup

Tags: vb.net, progress-bar

am using `VB.NET` as front end and `PostgreSQL` as backend, what i want is to create a progress bar while taking backup

code to take backup

```
Public Sub pgBackup(ByVal DestinationPath As String)
    Dim bak As New PgSqlDump
    Try
        bak.Connection = Myconnstr
        Myconnstr.Open()
        bak.ObjectTypes = PgSqlDumpObjects.All
        bak.Mode = Devart.Common.DumpMode.All
        bak.Backup(DestinationPath)
        Myconnstr.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "RStari9 - pgBackup")
    End Try
```

How can i use a `ProgressBar Control` on  `bak.Backup(DestinationPath)`

Comment: Which one.. Indeterminate style progress bar or determinate? Determinate style depends on a) count of database objects.. Tables, Views, Stored procedures etc. b) count of records in each table

Comment: @Coder need `count of database objects.. Tables, Views, Stored procedures et`